# Trying to create a child page in a Confluence Space using REST API

Tags: postman, confluence-rest-api

I am trying to do a POST request on my company's Confluence to make a page using the REST API. When I attempt to do it, I get a JSON response saying that it is forbidden. I am able to make a page from the GUI, but not with the REST API. I have done Bearer Authentication for the query. Here is a picture of the request and the response.

My question : how can I make the page on the Confluence space with the REST API?

[request + HTTP error response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0bsS.png)

I have tried so many things available on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like an authorization problem.

Authentication is when you sign in (login + password or token based or MFA) so it answers the question "which user is this?" (usually a login + a password to prove your identity), but authorization answers the question "which user is allowed to create a page in this space?".

So that has to do with the roles/privileges of the user that you logged in using Bearer Authentication ...